# How can I find out why AutoFixture is throwing Kernel.OmitSpecimen exception

Tags: autofixture

I am working on a fairly nested model which has some circular references. It also uses Entity Framework so all lists are `ICollection<T>`. To accommodate this I am configuring AutoFixture like so:

```cs
_fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new MultipleCustomization());
_fixture.Behaviors.Remove(new ThrowingRecursionBehavior());
_fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());
```

When I try to create a type

```cs
_fixture.CreateAnonymous<Session>();
```

AutoFixture has a problem and throws the following error

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Ploeh.AutoFixture.Kernel.OmitSpecimen' to type 'The.Model.Language'

If I exclude the collection within `Session` of type `Language`, AutoFixture throws the same exception for another type in the graph.

Is there a way to extract more information from AutoFixture, e.g., the property that caused the error?

Why is AutoFixture trying to cast my type to OmitSpecimen and what in this process could have happened to prevent it from being cast?

I've created a gist for the stack trace [here](https://gist.github.com/3766612).

### Update

I have managed to recreate the problem. Given this pair of objects

```cs
public class Session
{
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
}
```

The call to `_fixture.CreateAnonymous<Session>();` will throw the cast exception.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace as well as the exception message?

Comment: One way to trace what's going on inside of AutoFixture is to add the TracingBehavior: `fixture.Behaviors.Add(new TracingBehavior());` By default it'll write to `Console.Out`, but you can trace to any TextWriter.

Comment: I've added a link to the stack trace in the question. Thanks for the tracing tip, I'll have a play.

Comment: I like the tracing, it is great being able to see what it is doing. I can also put the log somewhere if it helps.

Comment: That would be helpful, but a repro would be best :)

Comment: I've updated the question with some code to reproduce the bug

Comment: Thanks for providing a repro. This looks like a bug. I'm working on a fix.

Comment: I hope that I've now managed to fix the issue. Can you try with AutoFixture 2.12.1 (or newer) to see if it helps?

Comment: 2.12.1 has indeed fixed the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: All that effort and no answer to upvote...

Answer (score 0):

This works in a newer version of `AutoFixture`(for example 3.31.3).

This code does runs:

```cs
    public class Session
    {
        public Language Language { get; set; }
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            fixture.Behaviors.Add(new OmitOnRecursionBehavior());

           var session = fixture.Create<Session>();

            Debug.Assert(session != null, "Session should not be null");
        }
    }
```